# How to call a route config inside a controller in JS directly rather than from html a href on-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am relatively a novice in the concept of routing and Single Page Applications in AngularJS. Therefore i am stuck and your help in addressing my query is most appreciated.

**Background**

I have a page "Products list" which lists all products in a ng-repeat loop. When I click on one of the products link, the application loads a "Details" page (An extension of Page 'Products list' (SPA)) for that 'id' through a href call

`<a href="{{id}}/Details" class="button"> Details`

to enable the routing to the 'Details' page, we have created an app.config as below

```
in Productslist.js
-------

$routeProvider
    .when("/:id/Details",{ templateUrl : "../ProductsList/Details" , controller :})
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl : "/"
    });
```

This present flow works fine and I am able to open the 'Details' page when i am on page 'ProductsList' and I click on the 'Details' Button in the html for any of the products displayed.

In case it is relevant, the URL shows ex: [www.abc.com/list/4/Details](http://www.abc.com/list/4/Details) and the product details of id = 4 is displayed on the page.

**What is not working / What i need**

Now From another third page "X", where i get the Product-ID, I want to navigate to the product details page directly (without the need for a click on the "Details" button in Page A).

Since the module for this page is first created in the "ProductsList" page, I a getting the 'id' value from page X into ProductList.js and i want to set the URL as below to open the 'Details' page.

```
if(fromPageX == 'true')
{
var x = id+"/Details";
location.href = x;   // dont wait on page productsList.html, but open "Details" page
}
```

Essentially i want to call the "routing" function from the controller in the .js file rather than from .html file (on-click)

the URL on the browser correctly shows : [www.abc.com/A/4/Details](http://www.abc.com/A/4/Details)

however I get a 404 - page not found error as it is not getting passed through the routing config.
i tried Window.location.href, or other suggestions in various threads still i am unable to successfully load the 'Details' page.

1. Is this scenario i am looking for possible in AngularJS
2. What am i doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for all your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where your logic for page X is happening, but you have at least 2 choices. You can catch it in the `resolve` of the route for page X or you can catch it in the controller for page X. Catching it in the resolve would be preferable because it won't try and load page X controller etc first.

**The resolve way.** In page X .js file, add a resolve block that will catch the ID before the route resolves and will redirect.

```
            $routeProvider
            .when("PAGE_X/:id",{ 
                templateUrl : "../ProductsList/PAGE_X" , 
                controller : 'pageXController',
                resolve: {
                    redirect: ['$q', '$location', '$routeParams' function($q, $location, $routeParams) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        if ($routeParams.id) {
                            $location.path("/A/"+ $routeParams.id + "/Details")
                            deferred.resolve();
                        } else deferred.resolve();
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }]
            }
            })
            .otherwise({
                templateUrl : "/"
            });
```

**The redirect way.**
This would go into PAGE_X controller, but instead of `window.location` etc, use the angular `$location` (make sure to inject `$location` as a dependency)method - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

```
if(fromPageX == 'true')
{
var x = "A/" + id+"/Details";
$location.path(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! X is the third page, that has a separate controller and module. only the ListProducts and Details page load through the same module. 

For now (since most of the code was already there) I Used the redirect way  where i sent the id value from X to "ListProducts", and in the very first condition redirected to the Details section using `$location` and it works well. 

But you are right. it will load the ListProducts controller first. Will try the `resolve`  and let you know